# Dynamic Search Boxes in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Am not sure on how to do this but I will describe it and hopefully you all can come up with a good solution. I want to have a box (not sure if its an input of search box) that when someone types in the box it pulls values from my database and shows the closest match based on characters being typed in. If the word that is typed by the user is not there then when the form is submitted then the word is added to a database.

Additionally I want to have an add button next to the box, so that if the user wants to add more than one word they can. This means that when the add is clicked a duplicate of the first box appears which does the same thing. The values will be stored in an array.

Any idea how I can go about doing this?

Comment: Jqm offers Remote autocomplete, look it up.

Comment: For starting point you can use (as Omar has mentioned) http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/demos/listviews/listview-filter-autocomplete.html

Comment: What about the dynamic add to create a new input box